# Jasmine/Jest type conflicts

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, jestjs, karma-jasmine

I am relatively new here and would need some help.
Company I work for uses karma and jasmine for unit testing.
Now they would like to migrate some tests to jest.
I got a ticket assigned to me. We are using typescript btw...
I got jest installed, prefixed with .spec.jest.ts to separate jest test from karmas. And it works fine. Jest just picks up those files that are prefixed. But when i try to do some build things we do with our project I get the type declaration conflicts between jest and jasmine.
For example: node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:32:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll, afterEach, describe, fdescribe, xdescribe, it, fit, xit, expect, clock, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL, CustomMatcherFact
ory, CustomEqualityTester

I am aware that jest is build on top of jasmine but is there some kind of workaround, we want to migrate our tests gradually. One at a time.
Is there some kind of workaround to namespace the types for jest or something like that so no conflicts occur?

Tnx in advance for your help :)

I tried to google some workaround but nothing that would solve the issue came across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We excluded the karma types in the tsconfig and added jest types. The IDE now doesn't pick the karma types but it works for us since most of our tests are now in jest and very few left in karma and build process works now correctly since there are no more type conflicts.